# Clean Array from duplicates

Tags: php

I have this array coming form a DB PDO result, where users have made Hello there, I have this array coming form a DB PDO result, where users have made some feedback so it can be duplicated projects because a feedback can be either a comment or a suggestion

My DB Query

```
$this->sql = $this->dbh->query("SELECT idProject, title, excerpt 
FROM projects AS up
JOIN comments AS co ON up.idProject = co.idProjectComment 
WHERE co.idUserComment = $id");
$this->results = $this->sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

My Results

```
print_r($this->results);
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [idProject] => 25
        [title] => Lorem Ipsum
        [excerpt] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut...
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [idProject] => 25
        [title] => Lorem Ipsum
        [excerpt] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut...
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [idProject] => 25
        [title] => Lorem Ipsum
        [excerpt] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut...
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [idProject] => 27
        [title] => Lorem Ipsum
        [excerpt] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut...
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [idProject] => 28
        [title] => Lorem Ipsum
        [excerpt] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut...
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [idProject] => 28
        [title] => Lorem Ipsum
        [excerpt] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut...
    )

)
```

As you can see, I got repeated projects, but I need to get rid of duplicated projects

Can anyone help me out to extract only one project and not duplicated items

I just want to get projects 25, 27 and 28

Thanks!!

Edited: Added Mysql tag + the for loop

```
$this->json['projects'] = array();

        for($i=0; count($this->results) > $i; $i++){

            $this->json['projects'][$i]['projectId']    = $this->results[$i]['idProject'];
            $this->json['projects'][$i]['title']        = $this->results[$i]['title'];
            $this->json['projects'][$i]['excerpt']      = $this->results[$i]['excerpt'];

        }

return json_encode($this->json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: Please add mysql tag to the question.

Comment: @Mehdi tried this, with no luck, based on you link $this->json = array_intersect_key($this->json, array_unique((array_map('unserialize', $this->json))));

Comment: @maljukan Updated Question as you suggested

Comment: You need to use `$this->results = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $this->results)));` i.e. prior to json_encoding.

Comment: @Nick I did what you said and I only got one result, the first project duplicated. Thanks anyway

Comment: It works fine for me: http://rextester.com/NMP6505

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in SQL query add DISTINCT just after SELECT